# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow', even when tensorflow is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, failed-installation

I am trying to install tensorflow for one of my machine learning projects. However,  even though I have installed it, I still get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

To help illustrate this better, I have created a `test.py` file, with the following content:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print('Hello world!')
```

However, still the same error, on line 1.

**Relevant questions:**

I've tried doing many other answers, but none of them seems to help. Any answers would be appreciated.

**Here's some debugging outputs that might help:**

> pip3 show tensorflow

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: absl-py, termcolor, keras-applications, astor, six, tensorboard, keras-preprocessing, wheel, gast, setuptools, grpcio, protobuf, numpy
Required-by:
```

> pip3 --version

```
pip 18.1 from c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

> python --version

```
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)
```

> py test.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: try running the file using `python3.6 test.py`

Comment: `'python3.6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Try a `conda install` instead, as you're using Anaconda

Comment: Probably check that you have anaconda in your `$PATH`. Just type `$PATH` in your terminal

Comment: After doing `conda install`, I still get the same error

Comment: `'$PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! Special thanks to the folks at the Tensorflow Talk slack who helped me, especially @akofman.

It was a combination of 2 problems:

**Problem 1**

It seems that one of the reasons it was failing was due to one of tensorflow's dependencies being outdated/misinstalled/something. The dependency is `h5py`. I found out about this by attempting to run `import tensorflow` in the python interpreter (type `python`), which gave me a long stack trace, unlike the test file (see problem 2). I fixed this by reinstalling the dependency.

**Problem 2**

It turns out that I have 3, *that's right, 3!*, versions of python on my computer

`python -V` ---> 3.6.0

`python -V` (in an anaconda enviorment) ---> 3.6.7

`py -V` ---> 3.7.0

I was running my test file with `py`, which is apparently 3.7.0 (I thought it was synonymous with `python`), I guess tensorflow doesn't support that version?